# why properties file can not be imported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

The properties file is `src\main\resources\exam-binary.properties`. The content in exam-binary.properties is:

```
user.post.url=http://localhost:9000/users/newUser
```

The import class is as below, however, seems that the value can not be imported.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.ma2oo.model.domain.User;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:exam-binary.properties")
public class RegisterUser {
    private static final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Value("${user.post.url}")
    private String registerUrl;

    public User Register(final User user) {
        System.out.println("url print: " + registerUrl);
        return restTemplate.postForObject(registerUrl, user, User.class);
    }
}
```

I have `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which would cover all classes. And The method which would call RegisterUser is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/signUp"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView signUp(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    new RegisterUser().Register(user);
    return new ModelAndView("quiz_start");
}
```

The standard output is:

```
url print: null
```

Could anyone help that why `@PropertySource` does not work ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using this `RegisterUser` class?

Comment: Using like `new RegisterUser().Register(user)`, and I have another annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which would cover all these class, not very sure it's correct.

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Comment: Basically, you're creating the instance yourself. Spring is  absolutely not involved. Show us what you are trying to do so we can better help you.

Comment: I think `@EnableAutoConfiguration` would make spring enabled. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is that the instance of `RegisterUser` that you are using is not a Spring managed bean. Instead, you created it yourself

```
new RegisterUser() // spring has no knowledge of it
```

Why is this class a `Configuration` class? You seem to be using it as a service. Move the property configuration to a proper `@Configuration` class, declare a bean of type `RegisterUser` and use the bean in your `@RequestMapping` annotated method.

Comment: Thank you man, I changed as you said, and it works. Thanks a lot.